# How to concatenate timestamp in php received from the database?

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a timestamp from mysql database in a format: `2016-08-15 15:35:53`

I receive it like this: `$row['date']` and I want to have just `15:35` for example, i.e. `HH:MM` format. Would be even better if it were a 12-hour format.

I assume it is passes the whole timestamp as a string?

Thank you!

Comment: date and strtotime functions do

Comment: [The manual for DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php  something like `echo (new \Datetime($row['date'])->format('g:i');`

Comment: You should never assume what a variable is, `echo`, `print_r`, `var_dump`, `error_log`, etc. Output it and you'll know what is there.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it in MySQL directly? strtotime is a handy function, but it's also a waste of CPU resources, as you'll be forcing mysql and PHP to take the mysql internal datetime value, format it to a string, which you then convert to a php unix timestamp, and then convert BACK to string.

Just do the conversions ONCE:

```
SELECT time(yourfield) FROM ...
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('%H:%i', yourfield) FROM ...
```

Relevant docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0):

Solved with:

```
$time = date('H:i', strtotime($row['date']));
```

I don't know if I should delete the question... Thanks splash58